# pip freeze shows appdirs, packaging, pyparsing, six installed

Tags: python, django, pip, virtualenv

I created virtualenv, installed in it Django with

```
pip install django==1.9.8
```

after that

```
pip freeze
```

produces

```
appdirs==1.4.0
Django==1.9.8
packaging==16.8
pyparsing==2.1.10
six==1.10.0
```

Where all these packages are from?
How to get rid of them?
I worked a lot of time before with the same approach and the setup was clean.
pip freeze showed installed only Django.

---

I use Ubuntu 16.04,Python 2.7.12, virtualenv version 15 on my home and Windows 7, WinPython 2.7.10 at work.
Tried to figure it out but for me the problem looks like appear from nowhere.

Comment: I was confused with the issues. Re-try many times while those packages still exist.

Answer (score 3, accepted):

That are packages that are automatically added to virtual environment on Linux as newer python versions contain [setuptools](https://pypi.python.org/pypi/setuptools)

You won't get them on Windows as on windows setuptools are installed through wheel.

You don't need to worry about them.

Comment: hm, but I worked half a year before it.Went through some tutorials and installations during this period of time always was clean.Strange, but this starts to happen both on portable WinPython on Windows and on Python 2.7.12 on Ubuntu.Also I want to push my code to Github and run pip install -r requirents.txt. I checked Github of other developers - No one has appdirs, packaging, pyparsing, six packages included.

Comment: http://flask.pocoo.org/docs/0.12/patterns/distribute/  as you can see here setuptools are automatically added to new python versions, also requirements are mostly written by hand and not copied from pip freeze